# PHP - URL variables that look like pages `/POSTID/`

Tags: php, url

I'm new to websites with databases and was wondering how to make a url look like

`https://domain.tld/H34d2b`
rather than
`https://domain.tld/?p=H34d2b`

I had an idea of forwarding the page to a 404 PHP script, so `/H34d2b` doesn't exist but the 404.php could read the url and display the content; but this seems a bit messy and would like to check if there is a better way other than what I am about to do.

I tried searching for this but I don't know how else to search for this other than `url variables` and I keep getting `?v=` - which is not a format I'd like.

Comment: Are you using a CMS? If you are, there may be an inside mechanism to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Apache or a compatible web server you need to use: 
mod_rewrite - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html